# How do I get the PID of a set process in the handler of its own SIGCHLD?

Tags: c, posix

I'm writting a toy shell for university and I have to update the status of a background process when it ends. So I came up with the idea of making the handler of `SIGCHLD` do that, since that signal is sent when the process ends. The problem is that in order to implement the command `jobs`, I have to update the status from "running" to "terminated" and first I have to find that specific process in the array I have dedicated to it, and one way to do it is by searching by pid, since the array stores the information that is display in `jobs`. Each entry stores the process pid, the status (which is a string) and the command itself.

Now the question is:
Is there a way to get the pid of the process that called the signal when it ended?

Right now this is what my handler function looks like:

```
void handler(int sig){
    int child_pid;
    child_pid = wait(NULL);
    //finds the process with a pid identical 
    //to child_pid in the list and updates its status
    ...
}
```

Since `wait(NULL)` returns the pid of the first process that ends since it's called, the status is only updated when another background process ends and therefore the wrong process status is updated.

We haven't been tought many things from the `wait()` and `waitpid()`functions apart from that they waits for a process to end, so any insight may be helpful.

Comment: It’s not “since it was called”; the wait system calls report on any unwanted for child process, including those that finished before it was called.

Comment: I suggest to use `waitpid` because this will give you more information about the process that has changed its state. But don't do this in a signal handler. A signal handler should not do more than write variables of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`. In your signal handler you can set a flag to indicate that a child has changed state, and in your main processing check this flag, and if it is set, reset it and call `waitpid` in a loop with `WNOHANG` until it returns 0  and process all childs as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not a good idea to use wait in a signal handler, you can do the following to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
void handler(int sig){
    int child_pid;
    int status;

    child_pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WUNTRACED | WNOHANG);
    if(child_pid > 0)
    {
        // your code
        // make sure to deal with the cases of child_pid < 0 and child_pid == 0
    }

}
```

What you are doing is not technically wrong, however, it would be better to use `waitpid`. When you use `waitpid(-1,...)` it works similarly to if you used `wait(...)` and will not only wait for a specified process but any process that terminates. The main difference is that you can specify `WUNTRACED` which will suspend execution until a process in the wait set becomes either terminated or stopped. The `WNOHANG` will tell `waitpid` to not suspend the execution of the process. You don't want your handler to be suspended.

If multiple signals are sent to the same process i.e. due to multiple children terminating at the same time, then it will seem like only one signal was sent because the signal handler will not be executed again. This is due to how signals are sent; when a signal is created it is put into an exception table for the process to then "receive" it; signals do not use queues. To account for this, you will need to iterate over the `waitpid(-1,...)` call until it returns 0 to make sure you are reaping all of the terminated children.

Additionally, do watch out for where else you are reaping the child (note that if the child has already been reaped then `waitpid` will return 0 if you use the `WNOHANG` flag). I would assume that this is what is causing the behavior you are seeing of the status only updating when another background process ends. For example, because you are making a toy shell I assume that you are waiting for the foreground processes somewhere, and if you use the wait function there as well as in your handler you could get 1 of two things to happen. The child gets reaped in the 'wait for foreground process' method and then when the handler is executed there is nothing for it to reap. And 2, the child gets reaped in the handler method, and then the 'wait for foreground process' never exits.

Comment: *Also, `SIGCHLD` is only ever sent when there is something that can be reaped so it doesn't really matter if you use `WNOHANG` or not.*  Not quite true.  Multiple `SIGCHLD` signals that arrive can be coalesced into a single signal.  Per [POSIX  2.4.1 Signal Generation and Delivery](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_01): "If a subsequent occurrence of a pending signal is generated, it is implementation-defined as to whether the signal is delivered or accepted more than once in circumstances other than those in which queuing is required."

Comment: (cont) So it is possible for a single `SIGCHLD` signal to represent multiple child processes needing to be reaped.  In order to ensure all children are reaped, a portable application will repeatedly call `waitpid()` with the `WNOHANG` flag set until it fails to return a reaped child process.